# Make all UIAlertActions of UIAlertController bold

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I want to make all the `UIAlertAction`s bold. `UIAlertController`'s `preferredAction` only allows one `UIAlertAction` to be bold.

Is there any way to do it? 
Thanks

Comment: UIAlertController and its actions only support default, cancel, and destructive styles. There is no public API to change the font. Write or find a custom alert that does what you need.

Comment: @rmaddy: Its strange that it is possible to provide attributedString for keys attributedTitle and attributedMessage but not for UIAlertAction :/

Comment: Those are private APIs as well and are not actually supported.